# How to right justify the text of a button template in Facebook Messenger Platform API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a button template and is trying to display about 550 characters of text for the button. It comes as left justified, but the language I am using needs to be right justified. Only option I see now if to do left padding which is very ugly. Any good ideas?

Here is the output I get:
Universal Nutrition Animal Cut...
  السعر من المصدر:36.27$  ولا بشمل سعر الشحن فى بلد المصدر
  وزن الشحن: 0.57كغم.  وزن الشحن قد يكون أعلى من وزن القطعة  الصنف: منتجات الأمريكية 
عمان: الجمرك 0.0% ،ضريبةالمبيعات %16.0
عقبة: الجمرك 0% وضريبةالمبيعات %7.0

It should be something like this:

Universal Nutrition Animal Cut...
                    السعر من المصدر:36.27$  ولا بشمل سعر الشحن فى بلد المصدر
                  وزن الشحن: 0.57كغم.  وزن الشحن قد يكون أعلى من وزن القطعة 
                                                       الصنف: منتجات الأمريكية

Here is a reference to the template 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/button-template

Comment: The example output I gave came as left justified. If you can answer my question you can imagine what I mean by right justified.

Comment: No formatting options are available right now